# Using a variable as a partial value for another variable?

Tags: c

Is there a simple way to set the value of a variable to the concatenated values of other variables of mixed types?

For example, something that accomplishes the same thing as this...

```
int card=10;
char card_suit='c';
char card_picture[255];
FILE *x


x=fopen("streamy.txt", "w");
fprintf(x, "%d%c.bmp\n", card, card_suit);
fclose(x);

x=fopen("streamy.txt", "rt");
fscanf(x, "%s", &card_picture);
fclose(x);
```

But not dumb.

Am I missing something super obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) and its relatives:

```
char card_picture[255];

snprintf(card_picture, sizeof(card_picture), "%d%c.bmp", card, card_suit);
```